# Powershell BitsTransfer (https) with invalid certificate authority

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, microsoft-bits

I'm trying to automate the weekly download of a text file from an https site with a ps1 script. My simple attempts to connect look like this -

```
Start-BitsTransfer `
-source https://url.com/file `
-destination d:\test.txt
```

I get the error "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect". Is there a way to override this CA check?

This Powershell (3.0) script is running on Windows Server 2008R2 and the https://url.com/ SSL cert is issued by Entrust CA. I've tried to add Entrust as a "Trusted Root Certificate Authority" to the "Certificate Store" through IE8. No joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really racked my brain for quite some time. I finally figured out you need to enter the number in decimal not in binary or hex.

C:>bitsadmin /SetSecurityFlags myJob 8

The 8 will make the "Ignore invalid certificate authority in server certificate :true"

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753211(v=ws.10).aspx

```
C:\>bitsadmin /SetSecurityFlags myJob 0x011110
```

Comment: Can you pull the relevant parts of the link out and explain why this should work in this case? The answer is pretty thin without that.

Comment: Thanks. I thought Bitsadmin was being deprecated (?) and didn't want to introduce it to my script. Am I wrong? The Bitsadmin warnings tell me to use a cmdlet but I'm struggling to find one (or an appropriate method).

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford- I'm not sure how you get more "relevant" than providing the proper command line.

Comment: @Nyquist: Why are you using BITS for this rather than one of the built-in WebRequest classes? Is the URL in question publicly accessible (e.g. the one above isn't).

Comment: I corrected a typo in the URL. The website is public but the WA130322 ASCII file requires credentials (which work in a browser). I'm not familiar with the WebRequest classes and Technet docs seem to suggest bitstransfer was the way to go.  This is restricted environment so wget utils aren't an option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I needed to update my Root CA list on the server with a MS Security Update. 
And bitstransfer can not override a CA check.